# Got NullPointException when I sqoop export data from hive to oracle

Tags: hive, sqoop

```
 sqoop export   --connect xxxxx  \
                        --hcatalog-database chinaums --hcatalog-table bm_sy_travel_all_month \
                        --username xxx  --password  xxx \
                        --batch  \
                        --call PROC_BM_SY_TRAVEL_ALL_MONTH \
                        --hcatalog-partition-keys pt --hcatalog-partition-values '2016-10' \
                        --input-null-string '\\N'  --input-null-non-string '\\N'
```

when I run the above code ,it throw the following error

```
16/12/03 16:19:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
**16/12/03 16:19:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1480326346381_0484_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: **java.lang.NullPointerException****
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportHelper.**convertToSqoopRecord**(SqoopHCatExportHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportMapper.map(SqoopHCatExportMapper.java:56)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportMapper.map(SqoopHCatExportMapper.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

**16/12/03 16:19:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1480326346381_0484_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException**
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportHelper.convertToSqoopRecord(SqoopHCatExportHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportMapper.map(SqoopHCatExportMapper.java:56)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportMapper.map(SqoopHCatExportMapper.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

and my hive table is orc formatted. And I am sure the connect words is connect.
how does this happen.....

Answer (score 0):

In SqoopHCatExport the column Name must match in Hive and oracle

Comment: I have let the column be same